# Eclipse: "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()"

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse, apache, ubuntu

I have a php script (machine_db.php) which makes a connection to mysql database as follows:

```
<?php
//phpinfo();
// 1    connect to mysql
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "abcd";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
...
?>
```

I am using:

- Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 5.6.11
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28

I am using Eclipse Mars and I installed PHP packages (addin or whatever it is called) for Eclipse. Then  I created a php project and added my php file to the project and did run as php cli application but I get the following error in Eclipse console,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

However I don't get any error when I run the exact same script from terminal like:

```
php machine_db.php
```

I also see that in my Eclipse project explorer there is a PHP Language Library which contains mysqli class.

Comment: mysqli is not enabled in the php.ini of the webserver, but is enabled in the php.ini for the cli version.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks. I am not running as web app. I am running as cli app. And you say it is already enabled for cli version. Then where is the problem?

Comment: The php.ini that eclipse uses does not have mysli extension enabled. Check eclipse's configuration what php it uses.

Comment: @shadow thanks a lot. I had not selected php.ini. Your comment helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget the db name:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "abcd";
$db_name = "my-db";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
```

You can also use

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.construct.php

---

Also try to install php5-mysqli

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-mysqli
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

dont forget to uncomment this line in your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
extension=php_mysql.so
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

Dont forget to restart apache server

```
  sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks $db_name is optional. my problem is not that I don't have db_name. The problem is that mysqli_connect is not defined in first place.

Comment: when i do "sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-mysqli" I get the following message:
      

Package php5-mysqli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However, the following packages replace it:
  php5-mysqlnd:i386 php5-mysql:i386 php5-mysqlnd php5-mysql

E: Package 'php5-mysqli' has no installation candidate

Comment: replace by  sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

Comment: Why would he need to install php? It is already installed on the computer. Just because a modile is not correctly configured, you do not have to reinstall php from scratch.

Comment: I dont know sorry ;(

Comment: thanks a lot mickael for spending time. I apparently happened to miss php.ini config in eclipse and that was why it was not working in eclipse but it was working from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that if in eclipse i check "`use system default php.ini`" under `window->preferences->php->phpexecutables` it will magically work.

Does anyone know what is "system default php.ini"?

I do a a quick `$php --ini` and it returns:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

Comment: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini **is** your "system default php.ini". In Eclipse you can define under php executable setting to use a different php.ini file. This would enable you to use a completely different php.ini for development purposes within Eclipse. Php cli uses that  "system default php.ini".

Comment: "system default php.ini" run php cli without "-n". If -n is set, conf.d/*.ini aren't loaded